# sending mail through phpmailer error

Tags: passwords, command, phpmailer

helo guys i have been trying to send a mail through php script for the last 8 days first i was using the php mail() on the server it returned false after alot of searching then company told me they have disabled this feature and told me to use my gmail account  for sending mail then i googled it and found phpmailer swiftmailer and other software finally i decided to use phpmailer and included 3-4 files on my root folder as described here(http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=install#) i used this code

```
<?php
         require("class.phpmailer.php");
         include('class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug     information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the    GMAIL server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail->Username   = "myid@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxx";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->From     = "myid@gmail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress("hostimf@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through        PHPMailer.";
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
   echo 'Message has been sent.';
   }
   ?>`
```

it is returning errors that are listed in my firefox browser like this

```
2015-07-24 20:12:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2015-07-24 20:12:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2015-07-24 20:12:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: c2lkZGhhbnRiYWh1Z3VuYUBnbWFpbC5jb20=
2015-07-24 20:12:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y2hpbXB1OTQ=
2015-07-24 20:12:04 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 2sm16058566pdp.68 - gsmtp
2015-07-24 20:12:04 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2015-07-24 20:12:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-07-24 20:12:04 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`
```

this i tried on my wamp server 
pls help me i m going mad trying to solve this problem pls help..... thanks

Comment: your smtp user/pass is wrong. did you try reading the url that the error message contains?

Comment: i used my gmail id and password not that

Comment: obviously, but also obviously they're NOT correct, since the system is saying "password command failed". so, go read the url that's in the error message.

Comment: sory i misunderstood ... i went to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 and did both things the allow less secure app and unlock captcha thing still this error

Comment: OMG it worked thanks a ton marc B thanks a ton.......u r a life saviour man... thanks alot

Comment: That link is years out of date. Get the latest code and use the examples [from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).